# How to use insert_string query helper with SQL function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uuid

My database is using UUIDs as a primary key. When I insert into the DB (mariaDB), I need to do:

```
insert into table_name (id, parent_id, name,... etc. )
values (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()), 'a UUID', 'record name', .etc)
```

I would like to use CI's insert_string function, but this array:

```
$data = array(
    'id' => 'UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())',
    'name' => 'record name',
    'parent_id' => 'UUID_TO_BIN(' . $parent_id . ')'
);

$this->db->insert_string('table_name',$data);
```

...I do not think will work, because each result is escaped, so CI will escape the whole text including the function, instead of only what is inside the UUID_TO_BIN function in the parent_id value.

I am trying to figure out if this is a possibility for the parent_id to run the function given. Otherwise, I guess the easiest way is to do the conversion to BIN from HEX in PHP, but will that break the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `set()` method, which accept optional third parameter (`$escape`), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE on the `id` column.

```php
$data = array(
    // 'id' => 'UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())',
    'name' => 'record name',
    'parent_id' => 'UUID_TO_BIN(' . $parent_id . ')'
);

//set id column value as UUID
$this->db->set('id', 'UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())', FALSE);

$this->db->insert_string('table_name', $data);
```

[more on set() method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data).